# Is it posible to make a mat-step unclickable without affecting matTooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, mat-stepper

```
<mat-step>
   <ng-template matStepLabel>
       <div matTooltip="Tooltip content">End</div>
   </ng-template>
</mat-step>
```

I dont want this mat-step with label End to be clickable.I dont want anything to happen if i click on this mat-step .But need to show mattooltip on hover.

Tried setting pointer-events to none in css but mattooltip is not working.Note: I dont want to disable this mat-step.Just want it unclickable

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code.

Comment: its not clear please tell more about it

Comment: I Dont want to click on that mat-step.Clicking on that mat step should do nothing..But need to show mat-tooltip on hover